# improve python regex performance

Tags: python, regex, performance

trying to improve the regex below:

```
urlpath=columns[4].strip()
                                urlpath=re.sub("(\?.*|\/[0-9a-f]{24})","",urlpath)
                                urlpath=re.sub("\/[0-9\/]*","/",urlpath)
                                urlpath=re.sub("\;.*","",urlpath)
                                urlpath=re.sub("\/",".",urlpath)
                                urlpath=re.sub("\.api","api",urlpath)
                                if urlpath in dlatency:
```

This transforms a URL like this:

```
/api/v4/path/apiCallTwo?host=wApp&trackId=1347158
```

to

```
api.v4.path.apiCallTwo
```

Would like to try and improve the regex as far as performance, as every 5 minutes this script runs across 50,000 files approximately and takes about 40 seconds overall to run.

thank you

Comment: Are you sure the regexes are the bottleneck in your script, and not, say, the harddisk?

Comment: Disk IO is fairly low. Script reads the log file in reverse line by line until it reaches a line thats over 5 minutes old.

Comment: Is this based on profiling the code or intuition?

Comment: iostat -kxd 2 shows very minimal Disk IO during the run of the script

Comment: This specific case is about URLs, so as others answered, you can solve it with other tools. I suffered from this regex slowness issue - waited more than 2 minutes for a substitution to end. Installed the package `regex` - works fast and great! you can download from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
s = '/api/v4/path/apiCallTwo?host=wApp&trackId=1347158'
re.sub(r'\?.+', '', s).replace('/', '.')[1:]
> 'api.v4.path.apiCallTwo'
```

For even better performance, compile once the regular expression and reuse it, like this:

```
regexp = re.compile(r'\?.+')
s = '/api/v4/path/apiCallTwo?host=wApp&trackId=1347158'

# `s` changes, but you can reuse `regexp` as many times as needed
regexp.sub('', s).replace('/', '.')[1:]
```

An even simpler approach, without using regular expressions:

```
s[1:s.index('?')].replace('/', '.')
> 'api.v4.path.apiCallTwo'
```

Comment: The second approach fails if there is no `'?'`. Why reinventing the wheel ;)

Comment: @ms4py this is not about parsing URLs, it's about extracting and transforming text from an URL. Mind the unnecessary downvote?

Comment: It is about extracting the **path** of an URL and transforming it. And the preferable way is via parsing it so it works safely for every input.

Answer (score 2):

One-liner with [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html):

```
urlpath = urlparse.urlsplit(url).path.strip('/').replace('/', '.')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my oneliner solution (edited).

```
urlpath.partition("?")[0].strip("/").replace("/", ".")
```

As some others have mentions, the speed improvements are negligible here. Aside from using re.compile() to precompile your expressions, I would start looking else where.

```
import re


re1 = re.compile("(\?.*|\/[0-9a-f]{24})")
re2 = re.compile("\/[0-9\/]*")
re3 = re.compile("\;.*")
re4 = re.compile("\/")
re5 = re.compile("\.api")
def orig_regex(urlpath):
    urlpath=re1.sub("",urlpath)
    urlpath=re2.sub("/",urlpath)
    urlpath=re3.sub("",urlpath)
    urlpath=re4.sub(".",urlpath)
    urlpath=re5.sub("api",urlpath)
    return urlpath


myregex = re.compile(r"([^/]+)")
def my_regex(urlpath):
    return ".".join( x.group() for x in myregex.finditer(urlpath.partition('?')[0]))

def test_nonregex(urlpath)
    return urlpath.partition("?")[0].strip("/").replace("/", ".")

def test_func(func, iterations, *args, **kwargs):
    for i in xrange(iterations):
        func(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import cProfile as profile

    urlpath = u'/api/v4/path/apiCallTwo?host=wApp&trackId=1347158'
    profile.run("test_func(orig_regex, 10000, urlpath)")
    profile.run("test_func(my_regex, 10000, urlpath)")
    profile.run("test_func(non_regex, 10000, urlpath)")
```

Results

```
Iterating orig_regex 10000 times
     60003 function calls in 0.108 CPU seconds

....

Iterating my_regex 10000 times
     130003 function calls in 0.087 CPU seconds

....

Iterating non_regex 10000 times
     40003 function calls in 0.019 CPU seconds
```

Without doing re.compile on your 5 regex results in

```
running <function orig_regex at 0x100532050> 10000 times
     210817 function calls (210794 primitive calls) in 0.208 CPU seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Going through the lines one by one:

You're not capturing or grouping, so the `(` and `)` aren't needed, and the `/` isn't a special character in Python's regex, so it doesn't need to be escaped:

`urlpath = re.sub("\?.*|/[0-9a-f]{24}", "", urlpath)`

Replacing a `/` followed by zero repeats of something with a `/` is pointless:

`urlpath = re.sub("/[0-9/]+", "/", urlpath)`

Removing a fixed character and everything after it is faster using a string method:

`urlpath = urlpath.partition(";")[0]`

Replacing a fixed string with another fixed string is also faster using a string method:

`urlpath = urlpath.replace("/", ".")`

`urlpath = urlpath.replace(".api", "api")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also compile re statements to gain a performance boost,

e.g.

```
compiled_re_for_words = re.compile("\w+")
compiled_re_for_words.match("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need Regex for this?
I.e.,

```
urlpath = columns[4].strip()
urlpath = urlpath.split("?")[0]
urlpath = urlpath.replace("/", ".")
```